# Fluctuating number of files and directories

Tags: files, directory, python, python3

Situation: I have a Python script that will recursively and separately count the total number of files and directories. Below is the code:

```
def traverse(top):
    filecount = 0
    dircount = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        for f in files:
            if dirs: dircount += 1
            elif files: filecount += 1
            else:
                print("Error")
                break
    print("Num of dir: " + dircount)
    print("Num of files: " + filecount)
```

Problem: I get a different number of directories and files almost every time I run the code.

Question: Mind suggesting a reason why the files and directories number will fluctuate? Maybe is it how Linux operates?

Additional Information: Just want to make sure as this portion of my script is very important to the whole program

Comment: How long is a piece of string?

Comment: @SatoKatsura What do you mean by string?

Comment: without seeing the code, how we can give suggestion ?

Comment: A running Unix system will create temporary files and directories every once in a while during normal operation. Depending on what your `top` directory is, you may well get a different count on different runs, but you haven't said how you test this, nor what the results are.

Comment: There are many problems with your code. You probably want `filecount += len(files)` instead of the `for f in files`, and similar for `dirs`. This counts symlinks and other junk as files, you need to `filter()` the list of files if you don't want that. The result will of course vary if files are created or deleted between runs. Last but not least: you should do some error checking.

Comment: @Kusalananda my `top` directory is "/", and that is kind of the answer I am looking for. you wanna post it and I'll mark it as an answer?

Comment: @SatoKatsura I will take note. You wanna post the answer and I'll upvote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A running Unix system will create temporary files and directories every once in a while during normal operation.

Just opening a file in an editor, or sending an email, is likely to create one or two temporary files, and browsing the web may create and delete hundreds of files over a short timespan.  Also, a graphical desktop environment may do caching and other things that you don't usually notice, which creates and deletes temporary files.

Depending on what your top directory is, you may well cover directories that have a tendency to change a lot, like `/tmp` and all the directories under `/var`, and your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

dirs is a list of directory names in the current (root) directory, and files is a list of file names in the current directory.

I think you want something more like this:

```
def traverse(top):
    filecount = 0
    dircount = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
        dircount += len(dirs)
        filecount += len(files)
    print("Num of dir: " + dircount)
    print("Num of files: " + filecount)
```